# ExtJs combo filtering doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I try to use 2 ExtJs combos.

When the user changes the first one (change event), **I change the store of the second one**.
(very similar to country-state filtering. When user chooses country, I load the states to the second combo store).

Up till here, it all works fine.

The problem arises when I add a beforequery event listener to the second combo:

```
beforequery: function(record) {
    record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
    record.forceAll = true;
}
```

I do that so that the user would be able to search the combo more conveniently (also from the middle of the word and not only from the beginning).

And it works,

but when I use this beforequery listener, the changes I do in the combo's store don't always appear in the combo. Apparently, only when I add records to the store it shows in the combo, but when I remove records id doesn't remove them.

Does somebody have an idea as to why it happens?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ExtJs have a bug in the Store.removeAll() function.

(They clean all records, but forget to remove them from the store's snapshot).

I had to remove all calls to the combo's underlying store.removeAll() to a while() removing the items one by one.

Then it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The event function of events that start with 'before-' should return true to continue and false to cancel the event.

```
beforequery: function(record) {
    record.query = new RegExp(record.query, 'i');
    record.forceAll = true;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also should work with newer versions of extjs (>=5):

```
var allRecords = store.getData().getSource() || store.getData();
allRecords.removeAll();
```